# Как передать данные в GridView?

Tags: android

есть такой пример формирования GridView на основе переданного массива скаляров

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/116-urok-57-gridview-i-ego-atributy.html

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  String[] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"};

  GridView gvMain;
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);
        gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMain);
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        adjustGridView();
    }

  private void adjustGridView() {
    gvMain.setNumColumns(3);
  }
}
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rect"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а как реализовать более сложную структуру, где массив состоит не из скаляров, а массивов из 2х и более элементов?

**добавил:**

хотелось выводить более сложный фрагмент, например
item2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rect"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

как связать элементы передаваемого массива, с `R.id.tvText` и `R.id.tvText2` ?

Comment: покажите пример того, что хотите передать в `GridView`. Мне лично непонятно, что заначит `более сложную структуру, где массив состоит не из скаляров, а массивов из 2х и более элементов`

Comment: @metalurgus, дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с GridView, также, как при работе с любым списком, используется адаптер, который получает данные из любого источника (база данных, массив, GSON, HashMap) и отдаёт их списку. В данном случае - для GridView.

Для работы критически важны четыре метода адаптера -

```
public int getCount() { } //возвращает количество элементов, чтобы список знал, сколько элементов ему нужно построить

public Object getItem(int position) { } //возвращает данные элемента списка из источника - из List, ArrayList, БазаДанных и т.д.

public long getItemId(int position) { } //возвращает ID элемента списка. Обычно равен самой позиции (return position).
```

и самый важный метод, где и происходит формирование элемента

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { }
```

подробнее можно посмотреть здесь [http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/adapters.php)

здесь http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/adapters.php

и здесь http://metanit.com/java/android/5.1.php

Адаптер создаётся путём создания объекта, вроде

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
```

где класс MyAdapter наследуется от нужного предка. Например

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter { }
```

и присваивается для GridView через метод

```
gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

В целом, тему адаптеров нужно освоить очень качественно, потому, что это очень важная часть работы Андроид-программиста.
Удачи в изучении!

Добавлено:
Вот пример "сложного" итема:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_time, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
            viewHolder.ib_Ticket = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ib_Ticket);
            viewHolder.llItemTime = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llItemTime);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tvTime.setText(getItem(position).getTime());
        viewHolder.llItemTime.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_orange_gray_on));
        viewHolder.llItemTime.setClickable(true);
        viewHolder.ib_Ticket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTicketBuy(position);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

Comment: дополнил вопрос. можно ли усложнить структуру item-макета, и как в таком случае связать несколько TextView с значениями из передаваемого массива?

Comment: можно. без проблем. добавил пример к ответу.

Comment: не понятно как его вызывать? в моем примере `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);` передается макет, Id и массив. Как передать такой массив: {'текст1','/img1.png','текст2','/img2.png'} или более сложный { {'текст1','/img1.png'},{'текст2','/img2.png'} }  ?

Comment: Используйте написание кастомного адаптера - наследника BaseAdapter

Comment: не могу найти пример своего адаптера, работающего со сложными структурами, везде используется массив скаляров, можете привести пример или поделиться ссылкой?

Comment: Сначала давайте пример сложной структуры, а то может мы о разных вещах говорим.

Comment: @ravend, Вам достаточно создать свой класс, который будет содержать 2 поля типа String, и передавать в адаптер массив из этих объектов

Comment: спасибо, вроде нашел подходящий пример: http://metanit.com/java/android/5.6.php

Answer (score 1):

Если мы планируем использовать этот код, - очевидно что любую "структуру" мы должны отобразить в плоский массив  `String[] data` (просто потому что адаптер принимает плоский массив в качестве параметра)

Comment: не обязательно. Кастомный адаптер принимает хоть черта лысого :-)